# make: is there a way to wrap a command shell section?

Tags: makefile

In a makefile, is there a way to "wrap" a section of shell commands in order to save on the line continuation `\` all the time?

**updated**: my main area of concern revolves around stuff like `nested if` blocks.

```
@if ... \
  #do stuff \
else: ; \
  #do some more stuff \
  @if ... \
    # do more stuff
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll have to create a script with your shell commands, and execute it from the makefile, or stick with the backslashes.